# How to reference a regex match as a variable in python

Tags: python, regex, string

So here's my problem:

I need to separate these punctuation items '], [, ?, !, (, ), ", ;, {, }' from whatever character they touch with a space. For example,

```
"Did he eat it (the bug)?" becomes: " Did he eat it ( the bug ) ? "
```

I can do something like:

```
re.search(r'[]?!()";{}', mytext)
```

But when the search finds a match, how do I reference the item that was matched so I can replace it with itself and a space? In pseudo-code:

```
replace(matched_punc, matched_punc + " ")
```

Or the space could come before if it's word-final, but I can hash that out later. Mostly I just need to figure out how to replace something with itself and a space.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
re.sub(r'([][?!()";{}])', r' \1 ', mytext)
```

Or, if you need to ensure that you don't get multiple spaces in a together, something like should work:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\S)(?=[][?!()";{}])|(?<=[][?!()";{}])(?=\S)', ' ', mytext)
```

<sup>Note: Thanks to [*perreal*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20343499/1715579) for making this click for me.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You would reference it with groups, like so (using your code as an example):

```
match = re.search(r'[]?!()";{}', mytext)
if match:
    replace(match.group(0), match.group(0) + " ")
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative us to use lookaround expressions to do insertion instead of substitution:

```
print re.sub(r'(?<=[][?!()"])(?=[^ ])', ' ', 
        re.sub(r'(?<=[^ ])(?=[\[\]?!()"])', ' ', mytext))
```

*Prints:*

```
Did he eat it ( the bug ) ?
```

Comment: +1 I was trying to figure out how to do make sure you don't get multiple spaces when your answer popped up. For reason this didn't occur to me, guess I need to get some sleep :)